# What may cause an app to not detect properly a home button press soemtimes?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I've an app which on a home button press it performs a certain action, most of the time the press is detected and the action is successfully performed.

But sometimes the press is not detected for no apparent reason. The press is detected via this receiver:

```
@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {
                String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);
                [...] 
                        if (reason.equals(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY)) {
                            mListener.onHomePressed();
                            [...]                        

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Why could such a thing happen? Is there any way so if it gets pressed it always fires that onReceive?

Answer (score 1):

> Why could such a thing happen?

You will not receive that broadcast if your app is in the background and you registered the receiver via `registerReceiver()`. Also, I do not know if there is a requirement for all devices to send that broadcast. Plus, there are devices that do not have a HOME button (e.g., Chrome OS).

> Is there any way so if it gets pressed it always fires that onReceive?

Not that I am aware of.

I would focus far more on removing this functionality. Your app is more likely to be compatible with more devices that way.